# Calculate or fetch the clickable areas of an accessibility element

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, accessibility

I am developing an [application](https://vimacapp.com) that seeks to make keyboard-driven navigation possible.

The application finds all clickable elements on screen, and allows users to perform a left/right/double-left click on the element.

I noticed there are some `AXLinks` or `AXStaticText` that overflow onto the next line. An example from [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/live/2021/03/29/world/suez-canal-stuck-ship)

[image: axlink overflow]

The Accessibility Inspector shows highlights the frame of the `AXLink` element:

[image]

I can't send a click at the top-left or center of the element - that would miss the hit box. I would also like to avoid using actions (e.g. `AXPress`) if possible.

How can I figure out the hit box for elements like this?

Something I have tried out is to fetch the frame for the first line of the text element. The center of the frame would then be clickable.

```
            if let range: AXTextMarker = try? uiElement.parameterizedAttribute("AXTextMarkerRangeForLine", param: 1) {
                let text: String? = try? uiElement.attribute(.value)
                if let bounds: NSRect = try? uiElement.parameterizedAttribute("AXBoundsForTextMarkerRange", param: range) {
                    print("first line \(bounds)")
                }
            }
```

However, I don't seem to be getting correct values from this approach.

Comment: Upon posting this question, I realized looking at the Accessibility Inspector that there is a target at the bottom left area... The bottom-left should always be clickable since there is always text there. I'm curious if there are other approaches though!

Comment: Which values do you expect and which values do you get. Is the first line param `0` or `1`?